# What's the best pratice to pass data to javascript from server side?

Tags: javascript

I knew exposing web service is a obvious option, is there any other quick method?

Comment: check out ajax & query, you'd want to poll the server on an interval, or check out node.js and socket.io

Comment: JSON strings? Rendered HTML? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: too broad, please explain more what you're trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That question is too general to answer in any sort of useful way. But that said: a lot of people are using JSON for data interchange these days. If you're willing to use jQuery or another library, it's extra-easy to use AJAX to grab JSON and act on it. Otherwise, I imagine it's not that difficult with plain JavaScript either.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague, so I will try to answer it before some trigger happy mod closes it (sweet sweet reputation points!)

One option is [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). This lets you ask the server for information using [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Php) scripts

Client (HTML/Javascript)[[1]](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function loadXMLDoc(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
       console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
     }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
   }
  </script>
 </head>
```

It looks intimidating, but all you're doing is saying `GET` me the stuff in `ajax_info.txt` on the server, and when you do get it (`onreadystatechange`) write it out for me (`console.log`).

You can use the above and tweak it so instead of reading a text file it reads a `PHP` file. That way you could ask it to execute a PHP script, which reads the contents of the server (server type, database elements...) and returns it to the user. Here is How I do it (I use Dojo instead of pure javascript)

On the Client:

```
dojo.xhrGet({
  url: 'getUser.php',
  handleAs: "text",
  content: {
    title: "Mr. "
  },   
  load: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

on the server ('getUser.php'):

```
<?php
  echo $_GET['title'] . get_current_user();
?>
```

The server will concatenate 'Mr.' with the current user and return it to the client which will print out something like so

> Mr. www-data

Finally another way is to embed directly into javascript/html so when you load the page, the server automatically updates the source code (warning, this requires quite a bit of tweaking)

index.html/index.php [[2]](http://www.ntchosting.com/php/php-in-html.html):

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body class="page_bg">
    Hello, today is <?php echo date('l, F jS, Y'); ?>.
  </body>
</html>
```